# "chubby rope" with no intersecting/thin faces

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing, screw-modifier

I need to model a rope which is as similar as possible as the reference, which is a bit different from the ropes you get right after applying the Screw modifier, since the spirals are thicker and the overall shape is closer to a cylinder; I managed to obtain a satisfying result (highlighted rope) by playing around with the Screw properties, but I'm afraid it's not something 3D-printable as it has thousands of intersecting and thin faces.
Is there another way of obtaining something similar? Or, are those errors really not that important for printing as long as I make it manifold?

thank you

[image]

Comment: Faces intersecting are not printable, you need a clean topology, you should easily be able to do it with the Screw modifier

Comment: hi, thanks for the help. I've tried but it looks like it's impossible to do it without intersecting, just by tweaking Angle, Screw and Steps View. I've followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=arb7_hePfgQ&t=96s&ab_channel=FunwithBlender am I missing some other parameters or modifiers I should act on? thank you

Comment: Oh ok I may be wrong, I'll try to give a try

Comment: I managed to obtain something a bit similar and with a clean topology by lattice deforming a barrel-shaped cylinder, using Array and merging https://tinypic.host/images/2023/02/01/Screenshot-2023-02-01-145123.png it's not really a spiral but I don't know of any other solutions

Answer (score 3):

You can create this half circle, scale it to flatten it a bit, mirror (or you could rotate 3 half circles 120° on Z if you want 3 ropes):

[image]

Give it a *Screw* modifier, find the good *Screw* value:

[image]

Keep a non-destructive copy, apply the modifiers, press <kbd>M</kbd> to merge by distance:

[image]

To sharpen the hollow of the fold, select the 2 edge loops and bevel:

[image]

As you can see there are no intesecting faces:

[image]

Result:

[image]

If you want to give it more details, give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, a *Displace* modifier with some noise, apply, make sure that there are still no intersecting faces (maybe don't give any displace when you're close to the fold).

Comment: wow, thanks a lot. that's very kind of you